# "Manage Activity" or "Manage Volunteer"?

Tags: copywriting

I stumbled upon a problem for copy writing, whether to display the copy write as "Manage Activities" or "Manage Volunteers". These two choices is supposed to be the replacement text in the pictures below with the blue box. In order to decide, here are the 2 pictures of where to put them:

First,
[image: Picture 1]
Sorry for non-english content but I will try to explain. I have this "Pipeline Aktivitas" in the dasboard home. This section displays 5 activities of an organization. It shows the registered volunteer status in the certain activity. For example, in the "Workshop Online: Recycling 101 bersama Kertabumi" activity, there are 0 Baru Daftar (Application), 33 Perlu Briefing (Admitted), 0 Aktif Bekerja (Active), and 82 Selesai Bekerja (Finished).

Second,
[image: Picture 2]
Again, sorry for the non-english content. In this second picture, it's the same as above but the page only shows one certain activity, not a list of it. It basically shows the same thing but with thorough information of the volunteers.

Now back to the question: Should I put the title as "Manage Activities" or "Manage Volunteers"? My concern is that the title is confusing for users.

Comment: Activities are actions performed. Volunteers are people. Which are being managed? That will answer your question.

Comment: It's the volunteers inside the activity that are being managed. So, do you think it's supposed to be "Manage Volunteers" instead?

Comment: Yes, for the reason you just stated. "It's the volunteers ... being managed."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the confusion exists because the **assignment** of volunteers to an activity is managed. To come up with a clearer title for this you should try to make them more descriptive like **Assign volunteers to activities**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how my understanding of the scenario goes:

##### Manage Activities

- Implies that the actions would independently impact only the activities
- Actions might include creating, editing or deleting activities etc.

##### Manage Volunteers

- Implies that the actions would independently impact only the volunteers
- Actions might include moderating volunteer privileges, accepting new volunteers, removing volunteers etc.

Since you are neither independently managing activity on the screen, i.e., creating, editing or deleting activities, nor managing what volunteers can do on the platform or whether they belong to the platform, neither of the titles justify the scenario in question.

The title should attempt to elaborate the scenario in question and what actions you can perform on the screen. Further, since the volunteers are being allocated to the activities (and not the other way around), your title should reflect the relationship. Hence the title, in my opinion should be **Manage Activity Volunteers**.

If the screen purely corresponds to assigning volunteers to activities and doesn't allow the user to perform any other action, the title can be **Assign Volunteers to Activities** as @jazZRo has appropriately pointed out in his answer.

If otherwise, the page corresponds to managing activities, i.e., if you can create new activity from the same page, or edit and delete any existing activity, the page can be redesigned to avail activities the center stage and be labelled **Manage Activities**. In such a scenario, the **Manage Volunteers** title can be a section on the detail page of each of the activities.